Can a generic Blazor Component handle multiple classes with the same structure?
I have created a Blazor Component to handle editing a database record which is defined by a class.
I would like this component to be reused to edit other records - that have the same structure, but different field names.
For example, here is one of my class definitions:
public class AccountTypeCode
{
    public int AccountTypeId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string AccountType { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    [Required]
    public string? AccountTypeDescription { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string AdditionalInformation { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public int DisplayOrder { get; set; } = 0;
    public DateOnly? DateTerminated { get; set; }
}

Another class might refer to CustomerTypeId, CustomerType, CustomerTypeDescription, etc.
In my component's @code section I currently have code like:
if (recordEdit is not null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(recordEdit.AccountType))
{
    onSaveButton(recordEdit.AccountType);
}

Where recordEdit is of type AccountTypeCode.
What I want to do is replace, for example, recordEdit.AccountType with a generic recordEdit.RecordType
By doing this I can reuse my component many times without having to write a new component for each table that I want to edit.
This is what my component looks like:


You can use an Interface or a generic type and use Reflection.
For example, create an IRecordType Interface:
public interface IRecordType
{
    string RecordType { get; set; }
    string? RecordDescription { get; set; }
    string AdditionalInformation { get; set; }
    int DisplayOrder { get; set; }
    DateOnly? DateTerminated { get; set; }
}

Now you should implement it your related classes (for the AccountTypeCode and CustomerTypeCode if that's its class name):
public class AccountTypeCode : IRecordType
{
    public int AccountTypeId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string AccountType { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    [Required]
    public string? AccountTypeDescription { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string AdditionalInformation { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public int DisplayOrder { get; set; } = 0;
    public DateOnly? DateTerminated { get; set; }

    // here is the implementation of the interface properties
    string IRecordType.RecordType
    {
        get => AccountType;
        set => AccountType = value;
    }
    string? IRecordType.RecordDescription
    {
        get => AccountTypeDescription;
        set => AccountTypeDescription = value;
    }
}

Now in your razor component add the @typeparam directive to basically declares a generic type parameter named TRecordType for the component. It allows the component to work with a specific type that will be specified when the component is used:
@using System.Reflection
@typeparam TRecordType where TRecordType : class, IRecordType, new()

@*
   Some razor markup...
*@

@code{
private TRecordType recordEdit = new();
}

So generally this allows you to use Interface's RecordType and RecordDescription properties instead of the specific classe's properties (eg. AccountType and AccountTypeDescription).
For example in your Form component:
<div>
        <label>Record Type *</label>
        <InputText @bind-Value="recordEdit.RecordType" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Record Description *</label>
        <InputText @bind-Value="recordEdit.RecordDescription" />
    </div>

Also please conside refactoring your classes and properties names, it is a good practice to name your id property just as Id, your class name from AccountTypeCode to AccountType and AcountType string in this context to AccountTypeName string.
Hope this helps.
Edit
Use or call your component this way:
<GenericEditComponent TRecordType="AccountTypeCode" />
<GenericEditComponent TRecordType="CustomerTypeCode" />


[polite] one point - "it is a good practice to name your id property just as Id,...".  I think a lot of people would take issue with you on that recommendation.

@MrCakaShaunCurtis I'd love to recommend The Standard as it not only emphasizes general standardized naming convention, but is also an eye-opening experience for me.

NP ;-), and excellent resource.  I admire a lot of Hassan's work too, but not everyone agrees with everything he sets out in his The Standard.

I've just downloaded The Standard to have a look.  Wow, it is quite some piece of work.  Something to study on those rainy days.

Thank you @mrSoh for this very thorough answer.  It did for me exactly what it says on the tin.  I really appreciate your time and effort in constructing this answer.
I don't fully understand how it works, but hopefully, with some research on my part, it will become clearer.
I take on board your naming comments also.  Thank you.
